# Add / Remove input fields Dynamically to form (Symfony 3 Events / Ajax)

Tags: ajax, symfony, events

I'm working on a small ads website, but I have this problem with [Form Events](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html) , when i try to add input fields dynamically.

Here's the thing, I have an entity Ad :

```
/**
 * Ad
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="ma_ad")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MA\PlatformBundle\Repository\AdRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Ad
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
 * @Assert\Length(min=10)
 */
private $title;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MA\PlatformBundle\Entity\Category")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $category;

/** @var float
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="speed", type="float")
 * @Assert\Valid()
 * @Assert\Range(min=0)
 */
private $speed;

 * @var float
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="area", type="float")
 * @Assert\Valid()
 * @Assert\Range(min=0)
 */
private $area;
```

.
   .
   .
Let's say i have two categories, Cars and Houses when the user select Cars the speed input field should be appear, when He choose Houses it's area input field and not speed.

I tried what is on the [documentary](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html)  so this is my AdType :

```
class AdType extends AbstractType
{
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    /**
     *  @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $em
     */
    $em = $options['entity_manager'];

    $builder->add('title', TextType::class)
        ->add('category', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => 'MAPlatformBundle:Category',
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'multiple' => false,
            'group_by' => 'category.name'
        ))

    $formModifier = function(FormInterface $form, Category $category = null) 
    {
            if( $category->getName() === "Cars" ){
                $form->add('speed',TextType::class);
            } else if( $category->getName() === "Houses" ){
                $form->add('area',TextType::class);
            }
    };

    $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) use ( $formModifier ) {
            $form = $event->getForm();
            $category = $event->getData()->getCategory();
            $formModifier($form, $category);
        }
    );

    $builder->get('category')->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, 
        function( FormEvent $event ) use ( $formModifier, $em ){
            $id_category = $event->getData();
            $category = $em->getRepository("MAPlatformBundle:Category")->find($id_category);
            $form = $event->getForm()->getParent();
            $formModifier($form, $category);
        });

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'MA\PlatformBundle\Entity\Annonce',
        'entity_manager' => null,
    ));
}
```

and finally the twig page :

```
{{ form_start( form, { 'attr': { 'class': 'form-ad' }}) }}
              {{ form_row(form.title) }}
              {{ form_row(form.category) }}

            <div id="dynamic">
                {{ form_rest(form) }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="well">
                {{ form_widget(form.save, {'attr': {'class': 'btn btn-common', 'value': 'Add'}} ) }}
              </div> 
            </div> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var $category = $('#ma_platformbundle_ad_category');

$category.change( function(){
    var $form = $(this).closest('form');
    var data = {
        'id_category': $category.val(),
    };
    $.ajax({
        url : "{{path('ma_platform_add')}}",
        type: 'POST',
        data : data,
        success: function (html) {
            $('#dynamic').replaceWith(
                $(html).find('#dynamic')
              );
        }
    });
});
});
```

So when i choose the category, nothing happened the form stays as it is.
I tried to make it simple for you guys, so you can help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are miss understanding something, the preset data event happens at backend ,so the form will never add the field by it self. You need to handle this with JS/Jquery. I would suggest the following...

> FormType at backend

```
$builder->add('title', TextType::class)
        ->add('category', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => 'MAPlatformBundle:Category',
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'multiple' => false,
            'group_by' => 'category.name'
        )
->add('speed',TextType::class,[//modify attr or class options to disable and hide the field])
->add('area',TextType::class,[//modify attr or class options to disable and hide the field])
)
```

> At frontend

Render the form as you want and handle the field with jquery.

//from your code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var $category = $('#ma_platformbundle_ad_category');

        $category.change(function () {
            if ($category.val() === 'some_especific_value') {
                $('#dynamic').find('some_specific_input_or_div').show()//or remove disabled/hidden
            } else {//some_other_specific_value
                $('#dynamic').find('some_other_specific_input_or_div').show()//or remove disabled/hidden
            }
        });
    });
```

At this point you can handle some how the switching options.

> At backend

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {

            if ($event->getData()['category'] === 'house') {
                $event->getForm()->remove('speed');
            }else{
                $event->getForm()->remove('area');
            }
        });
```

At this point you only handle the selected data avoiding posible errors.

The solution is to handle the add fields with jquery and set the data properly or remove the non used fields with form events.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Juan, I followed you tips and everything works fine.
Thank you

Comment: You are welcome, if it worked for you please vote up and select the answer in order to colse the post.

Comment: I selected your answer, but I can't vote right now :(